# How to interpret psycopg installation error OSX?

Tags: postgresql, macos, psycopg2

Having installed Python3 and Postgres 11.3 on OSX Mojave, ran pip install psycopg2 and got the following lengthy error message.

As far as can tell meet the requirements for psycopg and the below doesn't seem to fall into any of the standard debugging categories. Any suggestions much appreciated.

(ps circa 4 years ago had a psycopg installation running with postgres 9 no problems)

```
pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gk/0dzm94x90tzdbg6b9pw9lw140000gp/T/pip-install-5luc2ihi/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gk/0dzm94x90tzdbg6b9pw9lw140000gp/T/pip-record-r5dh3ovx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1712:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1817:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gk/0dzm94x90tzdbg6b9pw9lw140000gp/T/pip-install-5luc2ihi/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gk/0dzm94x90tzdbg6b9pw9lw140000gp/T/pip-record-r5dh3ovx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gk/0dzm94x90tzdbg6b9pw9lw140000gp/T/pip-install-5luc2ihi/psycopg2/
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally focussed on SSL error towards end of message  (ld: library not found for -lssl), found a comparable problem on the net and fixed by running install as follows

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
$ pip install psycopg2
```

More information on this error can be found at the psycopg2 GitHub repo: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/997